# 'User was deleted' removed too much of my reputation

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

I will get straight to the point: *I lost 155 reputation because a user was removed.* Now, my question isn't about why the user was deleted, it's actually about how to contact the administration to get back that reputation, as 155 reputation *is a lot of reputation to be deleted/gone!*

This is not a duplicate of

> [Don't throw away all the votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

The answers to that do not answer my question.

Comment: For clarification inlight of your latest edit, I linked to the one above because it's already the dupe-target to questions like [User was removed - Why does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294999/398063), [“User was removed” means I lose my hard-earned points?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187605/398063) and the like; answers being around the lines of: rep isn't everything, it's rare, you can gain rep again anyways, keeping the votes of deleted accounts might lead to system-gaming. In any case, I really don't see SE staff granting rep back again for such a thing. Sorry :/

Comment: Hrm.  Considering your rep at SO, all you really have left is a bounty you got.  That seems like the only one voting on your posts was a single user.  Which seems at least somewhat sketchy.  You have no less than *five* user was removed events in your reputation graph.  There's more to this story than we know.

Comment: @fbueckert The rest of the story probably is that moderators [have been cleaning up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373575/6083675) a sock puppet network where the socks were voting for regular users in order to look normal.

Comment: Check your inbox, we just sent you a message explaining what happened here. That account was not legitimate, so the votes should not have counted to begin with. You have lost no reputation beyond the votes you received from this falsified account, so none will be restored here.

Comment: Re the update: yeah, I don't understand why people downvote support requests.  You're not asking for a change in behavior; you had a misunderstanding about how the system works that led to a question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio They probably didn't read it as a support request, but as a "gimmeh back my rep" rant. When told it might've been a duplicate, all the OP provided was "it does not answer my question", without telling why. I can completely understand why that attracts down-votes. After all, the hover text of the downvote button sums it up quite nicely.

Answer (score 9):

It's really frustrating to lose rep through no fault of your own, especially when you don't have a lot of rep to begin with. I've seen people lose hundreds of reputation to this on small sites where that *really* makes a difference. :-(

Unfortunately, once a user has been deleted along with the votes, that rep is gone.  SE can't give it back to you because those votes no longer exist.  The best thing to do -- along with all the other users who were affected -- is to write more good questions and answers to build it back up again.

(Ironically, I lost rep to a deleted user *while writing this answer*.)

Comment: So did it affect your repcap?

Comment: @DavidPostill I ended the day 10 points short of finding out.

Comment: @DavidPostill: rep lost to user deletion counts as an unupvote, thus it's counted as part of the cap on the day the vote was made (not the day the user was deleted). For example, if you got 21 answer upvotes that day (hitting the cap), and a user who upvoted you once that day had their account deleted, you won't lose any reputation (as you still hit the rep cap on that day). This means that the user deletion won't have any impact on your ability to repcap today unless the user upvoted you today; generally, speaking, any rep lost to a user deletion is in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There is a contact form link in the site footer by which you can contact Stack Exchange team members and staff. I suggest you do that on the site where you lost your reputation if you want to contact SE.

Per [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) though, I suggest you don't rely on getting that rep back. 155 rep is not much and sounds like it was removed by standard procedure.