# Is it okay to delete all characters within a bad question that can't be deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-disassociation

Right now I am in a fix. I asked one question, which was received very badly by the community. I quickly realized my mistake and tried to delete it, but unfortunately, I already had 3 answers by then and the server didn't let me close/delete it. Even now, everyone is constantly downvoting it. My rep is going downhill very fast!

Now, you can't really blame me for what I did. Naturally, I edited it to say 'CLOSED BY ME. I AM SORRY FOR ANY INCONVENIENCE.' However, upon doing this, someone instantly edited it back.

What I'm going to say now, is both a question *and* a feature request. The question: Was/is it okay for me to have done that/do that?

The feature request: The author of a question should be allowed to ask for disassociation from any question that they have asked. This is an ethical issue, but also a policy issue. I'm *pretty* sure that it is illegal for someone to refuse a request of disassociation. If someone denies consent for a *particular* question to display their name publicly, then the authority should be given. The rest, I leave to you moderators.

**EDIT:**
Here is the question:

> ['User was deleted' removed too much of my reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316240/user-was-deleted-removed-too-much-of-my-reputation?noredirect=1#comment1039278_316240)

P.S: I am sorry if this sounds rude in any way(s).

Comment: You should be careful deleting posts here; you are most likely close to a post ban due to those downvoted posts, and deleting them just pushes you closer to it.

Answer (score 15):

> The author of a question should be allowed to ask for disassociation from any question that they have asked.

That's [already possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232), in accordance with the CC BY-SA rules:

> If you would like to have your name dissociated from one of your posts, you can request we do so by clicking on the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page.

Yes, this is more complicated than just having an option to delete your question, but that's for a good reason:

> If your question has answers, though, it's not fair to the people who wrote them for you to delete your question. They put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might.

So the answer to your question title,

> Is it okay to delete all characters within a bad question that can't be deleted?

is a resounding **no**. Note that repeatedly rolling back edits will trigger an automated 'rollback war' flag, which often results in ♦ moderators locking the post, preventing any further edits.

Comment: How do you do it then?

Comment: See the linked post: "If you would like to have your name dissociated from one of your posts, you can request we do so by clicking on the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page."

Comment: Just FYI, I have a pending flag on that question due to the rollbacks and in my flag I do suggest disassociation.